# How can I keep a logo over two different intersecting divs?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Here is the link for the site:
http://amfotography.com/newsite/clients.html

I am only using this folder for testing currently and it is not public.

As you can see my problem is that I am losing half of my logo. I want it at the same spot that it is currently in but I want the rest of it to show up over the header.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On logo's anchor link add following lines of CSS and it will do the trick:

```
<a href="index.html" style="position: relative;z-index: 999;">
    <img src="logo/logo.png" alt="Aaron Matheson Photography" border="0" width="300" height="82" hspace="1" vspace="10">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar is going all the way up to the top edge of your page. You should add a header block which has 100% width on top of the rest. The header contains your logo and probably other stuff.